# How to capture tool tip and its text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture the text of a tooltip in selenium. Using below code.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("age"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(XXXXXXXXX);
    toolTipElement.getattribute("title");
```

But the problem is I am not able to capture the tooltip element. Its shows when I hover but goes as soon as I move my cursor. how to capture such tooltip. Please help

Comment: Could you share HTML for this element as well??

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to acheive,

If your HTML looks like, with an attribute 'title'

```
<div id="header" >
<a title="I am an anchor Tag">Mouse over</a>
</div>
```

> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#header")); //Note: this is expected element
>
> String toolTipText = element.getAttribute("title");

or without an attribute 'title' on the expected element

```
<div id="header" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content">
<a id="aId"> Mouse over </a>
</div>
```

> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#header"))
>
> Actions action = new Actions(driver);
>   action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
>
> WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-tooltip")); //Note: this is parent element
>
> String toolTipText = toolTipElement.getText();
>
> //Your assert here